# How do I fish a Nibelsnarf?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

I've successfully placed bombs in its mouth, but I can't seem to find the right button to press for the fishing quicktime event. I always fail it really quickly. What button should I be mashing?

Comment: Are you playing it on 3DS?

Comment: Yes, I am. I have heard that it may take multiple people to fish the Nibelsnarf, but that's just hearsay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nibelsnarf can be fished out if it is staggered while submerged in the sand. He enters a trapped/staggered state which allows the player to approach and press A (with weapons sheathed) to begin pulling him out.

The easiest way to achieve this is to place a large barrel bomb and then throw a sonic bomb over it while the Nibelsnarf is fully underground. Nibelsnarf will then eat the bomb, which cause the staggered/trapped state when

**To succeed at the QTE, you should mash A and rapidly rotate the thumbstick in circles (left thumbstick if you have a Circle Pad Pro).** In my experience, just mashing A alone is not fast enough to fish it out before the QTE ends.